# UrlFetchApp POST not working, but returning Status Code: 200

Tags: javascript, http, post, google-apps-script

I am attempting to write a Google apps script to add new users to a site. Here is my function:

```
function sendPost() {

var url = "https://www.blackstonelaunchpad.org/users/sign_up";
var options = {
  "method": "post",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "cookie": "cookievalye",
    "origin": "https://www.blackstonelaunchpad.org",
    "referer": "https://www.blackstonelaunchpad.org/users/sign_up",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36",
  },
  "payload": {
     "utf8":"✓",
     "authenticity_token":"C4KXrxZS7rOPT2cmnL2avpuq8BC7fhtz3rVVbwkjYvk=",
     "user[program_ids]":"X",
     "user[first_name]":"Test",
     "user[last_name]":"Test",
     "user[email]":"scriptTest@test.com",
     "user[password]":"test",
     "user[password_confirmation]":"test",
     "button":"",
   }
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
Logger.clear() 
Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());

}
```

When i execute the script, a 200 status code is returned but no new user is added. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Status 200 code is a success.

Have you tried passing this using POSTMAN to see if it works?

Comment: Postman also returns a 200 but I have access to the full user list and it doesn't add the user either. Strange

Comment: The response headers according to Postman:

Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 16 Jun 2016 18:53:22 GMT
Expires →Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma →no-cache
Server →nginx/1.2.9
Status →200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security →max-age=31536000, max-age=16070400; includeSubdomains
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding
X-Rack-Cache →invalidate, pass
X-Request-Id →93758f53c85dbd70ee04bc4277bfeb35
X-Runtime →1.531773
X-UA-Compatible →IE=Edge,chrome=1

Comment: I would then suggest testing it in Firefox with Httpfox to see what headers the web page is sending through, but I can't seem to get a working email for it to accept.

Comment: Hi turtlepower. Only emails from relevant universities and colleges will be accepted. Try with one ending in @nuigalway.ie